# G+ Login Immediately Logs Me out 3x Using g-signin Button

Tags: google-plus, google-play-games

My code in HEAD is:

```
<meta name="google-signin-clientid" content="XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
<meta name="google-signin-cookiepolicy" content="single_host_origin" />
<meta name="google-signin-approvalprompt" content="auto" />
<meta name="google-signin-callback" content="signinCallback" />
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games" />
```

Here is my button code:

```
<span id="signinButton"><span class="g-signin"></span></span>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function signinCallback(authResult) {
    if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
        console.log('Signed In');
    } else {
        console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
    }
}
(function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

When I click the signin button, a dialog opens and authenticates me, then the following is printed to the console:

- Sign-in state: Signed In, Wed May 21 2014 17:31:05 GMT-0700 (PDT)
- Sign-in state: user_signed_out, Wed May 21 2014 17:31:06 GMT-0700 (PDT)
- Sign-in state: user_signed_out, Wed May 21 2014 17:31:06 GMT-0700 (PDT)
- Sign-in state: user_signed_out, Wed May 21 2014 17:31:08 GMT-0700 (PDT)

I have no code on my page that calls sign out, yet it is called repeatedly. The first two sign outs happen at the same time and the last one happens about 2 seconds later. I can't find anything in the documents that would explain this behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Not a good solution. If you follow the answer below and revoke permissions, it fixed the issue for me. That's not great, because it could happen to anybody trying to access your service, but the team at Google couldn't figure out what was happening.

Here is the link to the permission page: https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

Comment: yeah for me this is in live production code and is our number one source of customer complaints.  telling every customer to revoke access and re-allow is a huge pain point for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had similar issue, solved it by revoking access for my app in my google account so that I had to re-grant access to production app when I had previously granted my dev env access.

Comment: Yeah, I've found work arounds, such as logging in on an incognito tab, but neither of these are real solutions that will work for a commercial app. I've filed a bug with G+ and they have acknowledged that something is fubar, though they don't know what yet.

Comment: @mattsnider Could you please provide a link to the issue you filed?

Comment: If you have access to google's internal bug tracking system, it's b/15282009. The only solution we found was to revoke the access, as @Rikard suggested. Once revoked, I was not able to reproduce the issue.