# Getting user name and email from Google Login

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-signin

I am honestly confused. This is for a commercial product and my app permissions list their name and email as part of the google sign in.  My users very much want to give me their name and email, I am just adding Google Login to make it easier for them to do so per user request.

My code is just from here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/.

I am trying to let users login to my site with Google and to then read their name and email to store in my account database.

Currently the login is working correctly (I can log in and am writing my login token, client_id etc to the console) but when I try and request the email/name I get an error:

> Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.

I have created an app here https://console.developers.google.com, got my client_id set the allowed origin, etc and I set a logo and such that I see when I click the sign in button so I believe it is correctly identifying my account when the sign in button is clicked.

My code to request the user profile data is below

```
function _onGoogleLogin(){
  gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function(){
    gapi.client.plus.people.get({userId: 'me'}).execute(handleGoogleUserDataResponse);        
  });                                                                                         
  function handleGoogleUserDataResponse(resp) {                                               
    console.log("google user data", resp);                                                    
  }
}
```

Do I need a paid account on the Google Developer platform to access this information more than once or twice a day? That seems insane.  I am using Facebook login already and with FB the process was trivially simple and free.

I assume I am doing something stupid wrong.  Do I need to separately give my client_id to gapi or something?  Currently I just have this for the signin button per their documentation.

```
<meta name="google-signin-clientid" content="CLIENT_ID" />
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You want to get password too???

Comment: What?  My app is scoped and clearly asks for their email and name when they sign in with google.  It is for a commercial product and my users are happy to share the information...  Of course I don't want their google password, I don't want any information that they don't agree to give me!  But if a customer wants to pay to use my service then I need their name and they want to give it to me, I want that to be easy for them!

Comment: Did you do all of these steps? `You must create a Google Developers Console project, create an OAuth 2.0 client ID, and register your JavaScript origins and redirect URIs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that users are being signed out immediately.  This is due to a known bug in the google login system, more details are here:

[G+ Login Immediately Logs Me out 3x Using g-signin Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796014/g-login-immediately-logs-me-out-3x-using-g-signin-button)

This is exactly the behavior I am encountering.

Comment: If it's the Chrome profile issue, then either clear cookies OR use incognito browser. The way Chrome handle profiles sometimes confuses APIs

Comment: I see thank you.  Obviously I can't expect all my customers to do that so this may be a bit problematic, will explore workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You did not follow all the steps in the document.

When you make an API call, you need to have the proper Client-ID setup so Google can track which Application is making which call. It's used for authentication as well as usage tracking. You get free test API calls but if you want to make REAL use of the API, you must follow the document and set everything up.

You DO NOT need to enable billing as long as you use minimum amount of API calls, there's a daily free quota.

===---===

If you have the proper Client-ID setup but the API calls are still using unauthenticated credentials, then try an incognito browser. Chrome sometimes does weird things when it comes to multi-profiles.

Comment: As I said in the OP I actually did create an app and go through all those steps and the CLIENT_ID in the code above is actually using my own real ID, i just didn't want that in the post.  It appears the issue is due to a big in the login system, will post more shortly

Comment: I think I know what you mean. The ERROR you encountered is exactly that "The profile making the API call isn't authenticated". So either it's not setup properly, OR it's not using the correct profile in your Chrome browser. That error would make sense if you had multiple profiles in your Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

From the response, you get the credential and then you have to decode it from `jwt_decode(npm)` like this:

```
var decoded = jwt_decode(res.credential);
```

Then you get an object through which you can access email, picture and name. Then, store it in storage and parse it to use.